# Can light switch boxes be mounted one over the other

Tags: electrical, switch, placement

Does electrical code (Leon County, FL) allow light switch boxes to be mounted over one another?

I want to move a light switch. Ideally the new location would be directly behind another switch in the adjacent room but of course that can't be done because the wall is not thick enough.

Instead, could I put the switch box above the light switch box facing the adjacent room?

Comment: Should be able to do it.  Will to make sure the cables are not rubbing/touching on the backside of the boxes(metal box)(not cable friendly, shape edges, pointy screws).

Comment: Using an "old work" plastic box with rounded back edges that do touch the romex for the lower box. The 2 boxes will be a few inches apart due to cables coming out of top of the lower box. Any problem with that?

Comment: Should not be.  As long as the cables are safe from damage, then placement of the boxes are up to you(within reason).

Comment: So you want to put 2 switches *back to back* but you say the wall isn't thick enough?  How thick is the wall?

Comment: Don't US boxes come in different depths, 1/2, 3/4, 1" etc?

Comment: @Tetsujin They do come in different depths. But if you have a small box then you often don't have space for a smart switch or dimmer.

Comment: Why not mount the box "next to" the existing rather than above?  I know you'd hardly ever see them at the same time, but keeping the height consistent is less visually jarring.  To do that, you'd either mount an "old-work" box to the drywall, or if the drywall hasn't been installed yet, there are metal straps you mount between studs for hanging electrical boxes.

Comment: 1970s house so walls are standard 4" (3.5") thick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have the boxes in close contact al long as it is not a fire wall.

The cables can touch the other boxes there is nothing wrong with that.

If a firewall 24” or separation by a stud bay to face opposite rooms where I see this most often is garage/laundry and some diy work on the inside or garage side need to be in separate stud bays.

If not a fire wall there is no box separation required also there is not a specific height for the switches so one room can be higher than another (I get asked this question often).